# Cloudinary React component not rendering width or height transformation to URL

Tags: reactjs, image-manipulation, cloudinary

I'm integrating Cloudinary into my React app at the moment. I want to display images at `300px` height (automatic width), and set format and quality to `auto`. Here's my component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Image, Video, Transformation, CloudinaryContext} from 'cloudinary-react';

const AddContent = () => {
  return (
    <div id="add-content">
      <CloudinaryContext cloudName="mycloudname">
        <Image publicId="samples/food/spices">
          <Transformation height={300} quality="auto" fetchFormat="auto" />
        </Image>
      </CloudinaryContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddContent;
```

This is resulting in the following image tag:

```html
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mycloudname/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1/samples/food/spices">
```

So, the `f_auto` and `q_auto` are fine, but it's missing the `h_300` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the 'crop' mode when resizing. Try with -

```
<Transformation height={300} crop="scale" quality="auto" fetchFormat="auto" />
```